# Laravel - convert result of DB::raw to an array of strings?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to work out how to convert the result of Laravel's `DB::raw` to an array of strings, similar to `ExecuteScalar` in other languages but for many rows?

In my resource, I call the method like:

```
return [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'name' => $this->name,
    'member_images' => $this->getNewestMemberPictures(),
    'created_at' => $this->created_at,
    'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
];
```

And then make a call to `DB::raw` for the member images:

```
public function getNewestMemberPictures() {
        return DB::raw("SELECT `picture`
            FROM `scraper_profile_data` pd
            INNER JOIN `scraper_collection_entries` ce ON ce.`item_id` = pd.`profile_id`
            WHERE ce.`collection_id` = " . $this->id .
            "ORDER BY ce.`created_at` DESC
            LIMIT 10;");
}
```

Currently `member_images` is set to empty, I can only assume it is because Laravel doesn't automatically cast it to a string of arrays. How can I do this with Laravel?

Comment: you are not executing a query, `DB::raw` wraps an expression in an object to signify it will be used raw in a query, it returns an `Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression` object ... if you want to execute a raw select statement to get a result you are probably looking for `DB::select(...)`

Comment: @lagbox thank you, I cannot see any usage of actual raw string queries in their documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#selectraw only chaining methods with partial raw statements? I think I would benefit from a code example.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-queries  is for raw queries ... the link you have is for Query Builder

Comment: @lagbox thank you, now that I am using the correct method, how does one get this to output an array of strings? I am still getting an empty return value from `getNewestMemberPictures`, do I have to explicitly foreach and call `->picture` ? There is nothing in their documentation for returning an array of column values, that I can see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using eloquent model for getting queries, but if you insist on using `DB` facade, you can `collect` the result of `DB` to get your desired results such as retrieving just a variable like `picture`.

*Note*: Result of of DB::select is an array of objects (instances of php stdClass). By collecting the result array, you can benefit from a vast of functions provided by [laravel collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections).

Below code may help you achieve this using `pluck` method of collection.

```
$query_result = DB::select("SELECT `picture`
    FROM `scraper_profile_data` pd
    INNER JOIN `scraper_collection_entries` ce ON ce.`item_id` = pd.`profile_id`
    WHERE ce.`collection_id` = " . $this->id .
    "ORDER BY ce.`created_at` DESC
    LIMIT 10;");

$result = collect($query_result)->pluck('picture')->toArray();
return $result;
```

Comment: Thank you, the reason I'm using raw is because Eloquent is built on abstraction, and with the level of abstraction it contains comes a very large performance hit on joins versus raw querying.

Comment: You're welcome. As you care about performance, there is a package that measure different aspects of the app in [here](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar). Hope it helps.